# how to add icon in tab in angular js >

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I am new at angular js,

my question is how to add an icon to a tab in angular js?
That's what I have so far:

```
<tabset panel-tabs="true" panel-class="{{demoTabbedPanelClass}}" heading="{{demoTabbedPanelHeading}}">
  <tab heading="Tab 1 some text ">sapiente doloribus deserunt et nam obcaecati recusandae possimus aperiam similique.</p>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab 2 ded">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ipsam consectetur sint. Nobis facere illo iste quaerat sapiente doloribus deserunt et nam obcaecati recusandae possimus aperiam similique.</p>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I'm adding `<tab heading="Tab 2 ded <span class="icon-print">print</span>">`

but it shows everything exactly as written inside the heading instead of rendering the span as I would exspect..

Please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you are using angular-ui bootstrap. Use `tab-heading`directive and put your icon there.

```
<tabset panel-tabs="true" panel-class="{{demoTabbedPanelClass}}" heading="{{demoTabbedPanelHeading}}">
  <tab heading="Tab 1 some text ">sapiente doloribus deserunt et nam obcaecati recusandae possimus aperiam similique.</p>
  </tab>
  <tab>
    <tab-heading>
      <i class="icon-print"></i> Tab 2 ded
    </tab-heading>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ipsam consectetur sint. Nobis facere illo iste quaerat sapiente doloribus deserunt et nam obcaecati recusandae possimus aperiam similique.</p>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue using this:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
      {{tab.content}}
    </tab>
    <tab select="alertMe()">
      <tab-heading>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
      </tab-heading>
      I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

**more about this go for** **[this link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)**

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I got the following error using `tab-heading` as suggested above:

```
'tab-heading' is not a known element
```

Although the tab works fine, and the tab directive is present in my local lib. The [documentation](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/tabs) suggests the following sample:

```
<tab (select)="alertMe()">
  <template tabHeading>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
  </template>
  I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
</tab>
```

That worked for me. Maybe due to a different version? Or some dependency or declaration missing. Feel free to correct me or enhance this response.